# Invalid route action when everything seems fine

Tags: laravel

My web.php is the one posted below. The problem with it is this part:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'agb-page'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_view');
            Route::get('/add', AddAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_add');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_edit');
        });
```

For some reason it throws and error:

> [2022-11-21 18:29:23] local.ERROR: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Agb\ViewAgbPage]. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid route action: [App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Agb\ViewAgbPage]. at /var/www/wdctue8/htdocs/active-security-Website/active-security/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php:92)
> [stacktrace]

If I comment out this part, everything works fine. Don't understand what is the problem with it.

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserLogoutController;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Dashboard;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Agb\AddAgbPage;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Agb\EditAgbPage;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Agb\ViewAgbPage;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\AllBanners\AddAllBanners;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\AllBanners\EditAllBanners;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\AllBanners\ViewAllBanners;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Banner\AddHomeBanner;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Banner\EditHomeBanner;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Banner\HomeBanner;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\AddSectionOne;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\AddSectionTwo;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\EditSectionOne;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\EditSectionTwo;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\ViewSectionOne;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Company\ViewSectionTwo;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Contacts\AddContactSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Contacts\EditContactSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Contacts\ViewContacts;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Contacts\ViewContactSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\AddFooterAddress;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\EditFooterAddress;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\FooterAddress;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Logos\EditFooterLogo;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Logos\ViewFooterLogo;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\AddPrivacySettings;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\EditPrivacySettings;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\Tabs\AddPrivacySettingsTab;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\Tabs\EditPrivacySettingsTab;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\Tabs\ViewPrivacySettingsTab;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Privacy\ViewPrivacySettings;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\AddSocialCategory;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\AddSocialMedia;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\EditSocialCategory;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\EditSocialMedia;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\ViewSocialCategory;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Footer\Social\ViewSocialMedia;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Clients\AddHomeClients;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Clients\EditHomeClients;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Clients\ViewHomeClients;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\AddHomeSection1;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\AddHomeSection2;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\AddHomeSection5;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\EditHomeSection1;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\EditHomeSection2;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\EditHomeSection5;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\ViewHomeSection1;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\ViewHomeSection2;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Sections\ViewHomeSection5;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Slider\AddHomeSliders;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Slider\EditHomeSliders;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Home\Slider\ViewHomeSliders;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Job\AddJobSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Job\EditJobSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Job\ViewJobSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Privacy\AddFooterPrivacy;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Privacy\EditFooterPrivacy;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Privacy\ViewFooterPrivacy;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\AddServices;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\Banner\EditBanners;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\Banner\ViewBanners;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\EditServices;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\Section\AddLastSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\Section\EditLastSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\Section\ViewLastSection;
use App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Pages\Services\ViewServices;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Agb;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\BaustellenbewacHung;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Centerbewachung;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Contact;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Datenschutz;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Empfangsdienst;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\HomePage;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Impressum;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Jobs;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Kaufhausdetektive;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\ObjektUndWerkschutz;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\OpeningAndClosingService;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\RevierFahrten;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\ShopGuard;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Unternehmen;
use App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\VeranstaltungsSchutz;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

//================ start Frontend routes ================
// homepage


Route::get('Userlogout', [UserLogoutController::class, 'user_logout'])->name('user.logout');
Route::get('/', HomePage::class)->name('homePage');
// ObjektPage
Route::get('/objekt-und-werkschutz', ObjektUndWerkschutz::class)->name('ObjektPage');
// Centerbewachung
Route::get('/centerbewachung', Centerbewachung::class)->name('CenterbewachungPage');
// Kaufhausdetektive
Route::get('/kaufhausdetektive', Kaufhausdetektive::class)->name('KaufhausdetektivePage');
// BaustellenbewacHung
Route::get('/baustellenbewachung', BaustellenbewacHung::class)->name('baustellenbewachungPage');
// OpeningAndClosingService
Route::get('/opening-and-closing-service', OpeningAndClosingService::class)->name('openingAndclosingPage');
// RevierFahrten
Route::get('/revierfahrten', RevierFahrten::class)->name('revierfahrtenPage');

// Empfangsdienst
Route::get('/empfangsdienst', Empfangsdienst::class)->name('empfangsdienst');

// ShopGuard
Route::get('/shop-guard', ShopGuard::class)->name('ShopGuardPage');
// VeranstaltungsSchutz
Route::get('/veranstaltungsschutz', VeranstaltungsSchutz::class)->name('VeranstaltungsSchutzPage');
// Unternehmen
Route::get('/unternehmen', Unternehmen::class)->name('UnternehmenPage');
// Jobs
Route::get('/jobs', Jobs::class)->name('JobsPage');
// Contact
Route::get('/Kontakt', Contact::class)->name('ContactPage');
// Impressum
Route::get('/impressum', Impressum::class)->name('ImpressumPage');
// Datenschutz
Route::get('/datenschutz', Datenschutz::class)->name('DatenschutzPage');
// Agb
Route::get('/agb', Agb::class)->name('AgbPage');
//================ end Frontend routes ================
//================ start Admin routes ================

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    // Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    //     return view('dashboard');
    // })->name('dashboard');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminlogin']], function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard');
// Manage home page
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'mange-banner'], function () {
            Route::get('/view-banner', HomeBanner::class)->name('viewHomebanner');
            Route::get('/add-banner', AddHomeBanner::class)->name('addHomebanner');
            Route::get('/edit-banner/{id}', EditHomeBanner::class)->name('editHomebanner');
        });
// Manage other pages banner
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'mange-All-banner'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewAllBanners::class)->name('view_all_banner');
            Route::get('/add', AddAllBanners::class)->name('add_all_banners');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditAllBanners::class)->name('edit_all_banner');

        });
        //============== home page Section1 ==============
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage-home'], function () {
            // Home Section1
            Route::get('/view-section/one', ViewHomeSection1::class)->name('manageHomeSection1');
            Route::get('/add-section/one', AddHomeSection1::class)->name('addHomesection1');
            Route::get('/edit-section/one/{id}', EditHomeSection1::class)->name('editHomesection1');
            // Home Section2
            Route::get('/view-section/two', ViewHomeSection2::class)->name('viewHomeSection2');
            Route::get('/add-section/two', AddHomeSection2::class)->name('add_HomeSection2');
            Route::get('/edit-section/two/{id}', EditHomeSection2::class)->name('edit_HomeSection2');
            // View Home Clients
            Route::get('/view-client/logo', ViewHomeClients::class)->name('viewHomeclients');
            Route::get('/add-client/logo', AddHomeClients::class)->name('addHomeclients');
            Route::get('/edit-client/logo/{id}', EditHomeClients::class)->name('editHomeclients');
            // View Home Sliders
            Route::get('/view-home/slider', ViewHomeSliders::class)->name('viewHomesliders');
            Route::get('/add-home/slider', AddHomeSliders::class)->name('addHomesliders');
            Route::get('/edit-home/slider/{id}', EditHomeSliders::class)->name('editHomesliders');
            // ViewHomeSection5
            Route::get('/view-home/section/five', ViewHomeSection5::class)->name('ViewHomeSection5');
            Route::get('/add-home/section/five', AddHomeSection5::class)->name('Add_Home_Section5');
            Route::get('/edit-home/section/five/{id}', EditHomeSection5::class)->name('edit_Home_Section5');
        });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage-footer'], function () {
            // FooterAddress
            Route::get('/contact-view', FooterAddress::class)->name('footer_address');
            Route::get('/contact-add', AddFooterAddress::class)->name('Add_footer_address');
            Route::get('/contact-edit/{id}', EditFooterAddress::class)->name('edit_footer_address');
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'social'], function () {
                // ViewSocialMedia
                Route::get('/view', ViewSocialMedia::class)->name('view_social_media');
                Route::get('/add', AddSocialMedia::class)->name('add_social_media');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditSocialMedia::class)->name('edit_social_media');

                Route::get('/view-category', ViewSocialCategory::class)->name('view_socialMediaCat');
                Route::get('/add-category', AddSocialCategory::class)->name('Add_socialMediaCat');
                Route::get('/edit-category/{id}', EditSocialCategory::class)->name('edit_socialMediaCat');

            });

            //  ViewFooterLogo
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'logos'], function () {
                Route::get('/view', ViewFooterLogo::class)->name('view_footer_logos');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditFooterLogo::class)->name('edit_footer_logos');
            });

            //
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'privacy'], function () {
                Route::get('/view', ViewPrivacySettings::class)->name('view_privacy_settings');
                Route::get('/add', AddPrivacySettings::class)->name('add_privacy_settings');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditPrivacySettings::class)->name('edit_privacy_settings');
            });
            Route::get('/view-tab', ViewPrivacySettingsTab::class)->name('view_privacy_Tabs');
            Route::get('/add-tab', AddPrivacySettingsTab::class)->name('add_privacy_Tabs');
            Route::get('/edit-tab/{id}', EditPrivacySettingsTab::class)->name('edit_privacy_Tabs');

            Route::get('/page-view', ViewFooterPrivacy::class)->name('footer_Privacy_pageView');
            Route::get('/page-add', AddFooterPrivacy::class)->name('addfooter_Privacytext');
            Route::get('/page-edit/{id}', EditFooterPrivacy::class)->name('editfooter_Privacytext');
        });

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'agb-page'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_view');
            Route::get('/add', AddAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_add');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditAgbPage::class)->name('agb_page_edit');
        });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'services'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewServices::class)->name('view_services');
            Route::get('/add', AddServices::class)->name('add_services');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditServices::class)->name('edit_services');

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'banner'], function () {
                Route::get('/view', ViewBanners::class)->name('view_services_banner');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditBanners::class)->name('edit_services_banner');

            });
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'section'], function () {
                Route::get('/view', ViewLastSection::class)->name('view_last_section');
                Route::get('/add', AddLastSection::class)->name('add_last_footer_section');
                Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditLastSection::class)->name('edit_last_section');


            });
        });
        // home section  end
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'Company'], function () {
            Route::get('/sections/view', ViewSectionOne::class)->name('view_company_sections');
            Route::get('/sections/add', AddSectionOne::class)->name('add_company_section1');
            Route::get('/sections/edit/{id}', EditSectionOne::class)->name('edit_company_section1');

            // ViewSectionTwo
            Route::get('/section2/view', ViewSectionTwo::class)->name('viewCompanySections2');
            Route::get('/section2/add', AddSectionTwo::class)->name('addCompanySections2');
            Route::get('/section2/edit/{id}', EditSectionTwo::class)->name('editCompanySections2');

        });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'job-section'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewJobSection::class)->name('view_job_section');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}', EditJobSection::class)->name('edit_job_section');
            Route::get('/add', AddJobSection::class)->name('add_last_section');
        });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'Contacts'], function () {
            Route::get('/view', ViewContacts::class)->name('view_Contacts');


            Route::get('/view-section', ViewContactSection::class)->name('Manage_Contacts_section');
            Route::get('/add-section', AddContactSection::class)->name('Add_Contacts_section');
            Route::get('/edit-section/{id}', EditContactSection::class)->name('edit_Contacts_section');


        });


        // middle ware end
    });
    // middle ware end


// Manage home page


});
//================ end admin routes ================
```

Comment: is `ViewAgbPage` invokable?

Comment: If you mean the `__invoke` method, no it's not. But none of the pages are.

Comment: if you are pointing an action directly at a controller they have to be invokable since you are not pointing to a method of the controller (perhaps these "controllers" you have are inheriting from something that already provides that method)